# Conda install basemap error

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to install matplotlib-basemap through Anaconda prompt, but it's just not working.

When I type:

```
conda install basemap
```

The error it gives is:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - basemap
  - xlsxwriter
```

Does this mean I need to unistall xlsxwriter (even though I need it)?  How do I unistall this then?

I also tried downloading it through https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#basemap:

```
pip install basemap-1.1.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
```

but then the error is:

```
basemap-1.1.0-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It worked when I typed in:

```
conda install -c conda-forge basemap
```

Comment: Next step is installing `cartopy`.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do the same thing several times. Run as administration>>> "Anacodna Prompt" then type:

```
conda install -c conda-forge basemap
```

it worked for me.